# Destroying exact object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a small 2d game in which you need to survive. Each tree has its own strength = 5. When the player collides and presses the left mouse button then strength is -1 and player wood stat is +1. when the tree strength is equal or less than 0 then the tree is destroyed. Here is my code : (Question is after the code)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Stats: MonoBehaviour
{
    //Player Stats
    public float hp = 100;
    public float wood = 0;

    //Tree stats
    public float treeLogStrenth = 5;

    //Text
    public Text woodText;

    void Start ()
    {
        woodText.text = "0";
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        woodText.text = wood.ToString();

        if (treeLogStrenth <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(GetComponent<PlayerCollisions>().;
        }
    }
}
```

here is another code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollisions: MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnCollisionStay2D (Collision2D collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.gameObject.tag == "Tree" && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            string treeName = collisionInfo.gameObject.name;
            GetComponent<Stats>().wood += 1;
            GetComponent<Stats>().treeLogStrenth -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**MY QUESTION** : How to make instead of creating all the time another game object for each tree and destroying it, only like one simple code that will do it. please help (UNITY NEWEST VERSION)

Comment: This is JavaScript? - I removed the JavaScript tag, because either this is _JAVA_ or C# which is already tagged.

Comment: `Destroy(GetComponent<PlayerCollisions>().;` is incomplete code

Comment: Are you *really* using Visual Studio 2010?! Either way, the tag is not needed.

Comment: I don´t get your question. When you need 100 trees, you have to create 100, in order to destroy them. Of course every tree has its own collider, so you can determine which which of the trees you collided.

Answer (score 0):

So to clear things up: `Stats` should be attached to the player, right?

You should not do things every frame in `Update` but rather event driven like

```
public class Stats : MonoBehaviour
{
    // You should never allow your stats to be set via public fields
    [SerializeField] private float hp = 100;
    [SerializeField] private float wood = 0;

    // if you need to read them from somewhere else you can use read-only properties
    public float HP => hp;
    public float Wood => wood;

    [SerializeField] private Text woodText;

    private void Start ()
    {
        woodText.text = "0";
    }

    public void AddWood(int amount)
    {
        wood += amount;
        woodText.text = wood.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then each tree should rather have its own component instance attached like e.g.

```
public class Tree : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float treeLogStrenth = 5;

    public void HandleClick(Stats playerStats)
    {
        // if this tree has wood left add it to the player stats
        if(treeLogStrength > 0)
        {
            playerStats.AddWood(1); 
            treeLogStrenth -= 1;
        }

        // destroy this tree when no wood left
        if (treeLogStrenth <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

and then finally also attached to the Player

```
public class PlayerCollisions: MonoBehaviour
{
    // better already reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Stats stats;

    // will store the currently collided tree in order to reuse it
    private Tree currentlyCollidedTree;

    // as fallback initialize it on runtime
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!stats) stats = GetComponent<Stats>();
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("Tree") && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Get the Tree component of the tree object you are currently colliding with
            // but only once and store the reference in order to reuse it
            if(!currentlyCollidedTree) currentlyCollidedTree= collisionInfo.gameObject.GetComponent<Tree>();

            // tell the tree to handle a click and pass in your stats reference
            currentlyCollidedTree.HandleClick(stats);
        }
    }

    // reset the currentlyCollidedTree field when not colliding anymore
    private void OnCollisionExit2D()
    {
        currentlyCollidedTree = null;
    }
}
```

---

Well yes there would be an alternative where not every tree needs its own component instance but I would recommend to not use it actually!

You could make your player remember which tree he already clicked in something like

```
public class PlayerCollisions: MonoBehaviour
{
    // better already reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Stats stats;

    // will store all trees we ever clicked on in relation to the according available wood
    private Dictionary<GameObject, int> encounteredTrees = new Dictionary<GameObject, int>();

    // as fallback initialize it on runtime
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!stats) stats = GetComponent<Stats>();
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("Tree") && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // did we work on this tree before?
            if(encounteredTrees.Contains(collisionInfo.gameObject))
            {
                // if so gain one wood and remove one from this tree
                stats.AddWood(1);
                encounteredTrees[collisionInfo.gameObject] -= 1;
                // destroy the tree if no wood available and remove it from the dictionary
                if(encounteredTrees[collisionInfo.gameObject] <= 0)
                {
                    encounteredTrees.RemoveKey(collisionInfo.gameObject);
                    Destroy(collisionInfo.gameObject);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // the first time we work this tree gain one wood and add
                // the tree as new entry to the dictionary with 4 wood left
                stats.AddWood(1);
                encounteredTrees.Add(collisionInfo.gameObject, 4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this however limits you extremely and it is not possible anymore that you have e.g. different Tree prefabs with different amount of available wood ...

Comment: @MaxCieplinski what part of it?

Comment: wait you meant that every tree should have its own component? than thats a lot of code if e.g there are 50 trees

Comment: @MaxCieplinski well if there is 50 trees then there is 50 GameObjects with the `Tree` component attached to

Comment: Yes but is there any way not to make every tree stasts?

Comment: @MaxCieplinski I don't understand what you mean .... if every tree should have its own individual lifetime and amount of clicks it can receive in order to provide wood then no ... evevery individual tree needs an individual instance of the `Tree` component attached to in order to handle the values related to it.

Comment: Well see the update section at the bottom ... you **can** have only your player handle the values without a dedicated component attached to the trees ... I would not recommend it though!

Comment: no ... as said `PlayerCollisions` is attached to the Player isn't it?